# Dns with parallel resolution

Tags: domain-name-system, cache

I'm looking for a simple caching (can be caching-only) DNS server, which can do parallel resolving on its own. Is there something like that available?

Alternatively I know there's the c-ares library, which can do multiple-hosts resolution, but it's not a drop-in replacement for libresolve that I could use in the affected software. Maybe there is some other lib which can fulfill this requirement?

Comment: please provide more information about the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I need a dns server which won't wait before trying another upstream dns. It should query all 2 or 3 of them and return the first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at dnsmasq

Comment: With `--all-servers` it does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [GNU adns](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~ian/adns/) library.